# Visualizing transformed data with Python with 2 components

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scatter-plot, pca

This is the samplefile I am trying to analyze by first running PCA:

```
A01_01  A01_02  A01_03  A01_04  A01_05  A01_06  A01_07  A01_08  A01_09  A01_10 A01_11   A01_12  A01_13  A01_14  A01_15  A01_16  A01_17  A01_18  A01_19  A01_20  A01_21  A01_22  A01_23  A01_24  A01_25  A01_26  A01_27  A01_28  A01_29  A01_30  A01_31  A01_32  A01_33  A01_34  A01_35  A01_36  A01_37  A01_38  A01_39  A01_40  A01_41  A01_42  A01_43  A01_44  A01_45  A01_46  A01_47  A01_48  A01_49  A01_50  A01_51  A01_52  A01_53  A01_54  A01_55  A01_56  A01_57  A01_58  A01_59  A01_60  A01_61  A01_62  A01_63  A01_64  A01_65  A01_66  A01_67  A01_69  A01_70  A01_71
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1 
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
```

With the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    
data = np.loadtxt('/Users/cmdb/Desktop/Lab6_GWAS/variants1.txt', skiprows=1)
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
fit = pca.fit_transform(data) #Fit is PCA(copy=True, n_components=2, whiten=False)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(fit[:,0], fit[:,1])
plt.show()
```

*Please note I would like to plot the first two components, and as I understand I am doing that*

This is the plot I get: 
[image]

I would like to draw some information out it and make sure I did this right by performing PCA on the first two components.

Also, when I change the `n_components` in the `pca = pca(n_components)` to 2 or 5, there is no change. Any ideas why or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The two components you get with `n_components=2` should be the same as the first two components you get with `n_components=5`, so there won't be a difference if you only plot those.  The difference is that in the second case you will get additional components.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the shape of your result.

```
print (fit.shape)
```

The second element of the tuple returned should be the same as n_components.
As said in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) : n_components represent the

> Number of components to keep

If you want to visualize data that has more than 2 or 3 dimensions look at [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html) , maybe you can try [t-SNE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html#sklearn.manifold.TSNE) for reducting the dimensionality of your data instead of PCA (if your concern is visualization).